# Margin not working in CSS

Tags: html, css, layout

I've been looking for solutions everywhere but I can't understand how to separate the text from the iframe. Everything I tried did not work (for example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31331030/text-too-close-to-iframe-how-to-get-margin-border-around-it) answer).
This is a screenshot to have an idea:

[image: problem]

this is the HTML (I used it very rarely in my life and never worked with containers before, so I'm sure the error is clearly visible to someone more skilled than me):

```
<div class="container">
  <iframe src="link" width="500px" height="500px" align="left" style="border: 1px solid #ccc" frameborder=0></iframe>
  <article>
    <font face="calibri" size="30" style="background-color: powderblue;">title</font>
    <h4></h4>
    <font face="verdana">text</font>
  </article>
</div>
```

This is the CSS (I was testing `margin-left: 10px` but 10 or 1000px won't change anything):

```
article {
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body {
    max-width: 100%;
}

div.container {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

iframe {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS/HTML5 equivilent to iframe marginheight and marginwidth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286888/css-html5-equivilent-to-iframe-marginheight-and-marginwidth)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could solve it by setting `position: relative;` to your article tag. This way, you could then specify the position offset that you want it to have using the `left` property instead of using the `margin-left` property.

I mean:

```
article {
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body {
    max-width: 100%;
}

div.container {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

iframe {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

If this is not exactly what you wanted, I also think that the `position` property, together with the `left`, `right`, `top` and `bottom` properties, seem quite suitable for your problem, so I suggest you should take a look of them.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 does not support those for iframe style, there is no way to set them through style sheet.